# Problems referencing items in a kv with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

When referencing to a kivy item in a kv, why can variables not be used?

```
self.ids.top_left.background_normal = "x.png"
```

this works fine while "top_left" is directly an ID in the kv file and "x.png" references directly to a picture. But when i say something like:

```
button_pressed = top_left
picture_touse = "x.png"
self.ids.button_pressed.background_normal = picture_touse
```

then it breaks and gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

how can i refer to a kv item using generated references?

Comment: By the way, i have already tried using [ ] square brackets around the answer, being told that this may solve the issue making it a __dict lookup, but with square brackets i get a syntax error pointing to the first bracket, so that´s not accepted by python. I have also tried to restrict the type adding str(top_left) for example to make sure it´s being treated as a string, but there is no change.

Comment: awesome, variables can be used!, I have to make it explicit here (and it should go into the title/question) so that Google will find this and the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, just found the answer, for anyone wanting to do this, just create:

check_ref = {}

(call it what you want) then when refering to an ID call it before putting the rest of the info in square brackets, like:

```
self.ids.check_ref[button_pressed].background_normal = check_ref[picture_touse]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since kivy places all the widgets tagged id's in a dictionary type propety. Therefore, you can reference it using dict[key]. The solution is to replace

```
self.ids.button_pressed.background_normal = picture_touse
```

with

```
self.ids[button_pressed].background_normal = picture_touse
```

## Snippet

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen, Widget):

    def methodforbuttonpress(self, button_pressed):
        kivy_logo = "kivy-logo-black-64.png"
        self.ids[button_pressed].background_normal = kivy_logo
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: use of variables for ids or id, awesome